# Axis2 on Weblogic 9

Tags: weblogic, apache-axis, axiom

I am trying to use Axis2 on Weblogic 9.2 and getting errors.

My code works as I have successfully tested it in Eclipse.
When I run from my EAR deployed on Weblogic 9.2, I get the following.

```
Wed Nov 11 15:59:27 GMT 2015
weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.common.edsfoundationwindows.Frame.display(Frame.java:6461)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.common.edsfoundationwindows.Frame$AsyncRunner.run(Frame.java:491)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.framework.Task$1.run(Task.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils$8.run(StAXUtils.java:527)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.newXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:517)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory_perClassLoader(StAXUtils.java:597)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:171)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StAXUtils.java:223)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createXMLStreamReader(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createOMBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:134)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:590)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:575)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:90)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:857)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.interfaces.experian.service.MXINLiteStub.<init>(MXINLiteStub.java:115)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.interfaces.experian.service.MXINLiteStub.<init>(MXINLiteStub.java:101)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.interfaces.experian.service.MXINLiteStub.<init>(MXINLiteStub.java:150)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.interfaces.experian.service.ExperianPolicyManager.appraisalCheckAndValuation(ExperianPolicyManager.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy127.appraisalCheckAndValuation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.framework.remoting.PluggableRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(PluggableRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.httpsupport.SessionFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3251)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2010)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1916)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationUtils.fillInClientStackTraceIfPossible(RemoteInvocationUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationResult.recreate(RemoteInvocationResult.java:115)
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedAccessor.recreateRemoteInvocationResult(RemoteInvocationBasedAccessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:148)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.appraisalCheckAndValuation(Unknown Source)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.wholesale.edsaccvolwindows.AddVolumeWin.lookupRequested(AddVolumeWin.java:1765)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.wholesale.edsaccvolwindows.AddVolumeWin.access$500(AddVolumeWin.java:232)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.wholesale.edsaccvolwindows.AddVolumeWin$12.handleEvent(AddVolumeWin.java:2291)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.framework.EventManager$ThreadData.handleNextEvents(EventManager.java:716)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.framework.EventManager$ThreadData.waitForEvents(EventManager.java:802)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.framework.EventManager._waitForEvent(EventManager.java:1741)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.framework.EventManager.waitForEvent(EventManager.java:2051)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.framework.EventManager.waitForEvent(EventManager.java:2067)
    at com.gmacfs.wholesale.common.edsfoundationwindows.Frame.display(Frame.java:6416)
    ... 3 more
```

We use ANT to build the EAR and the following JARs are included in the lib folder of the EAR.

```
axis2-adb-1.6.3.jar
axis2-kernel-1.6.3.jar
axis2-transport-base-1.6.3.jar
axis2-transport-http-1.6.3.jar
axis2-transport-local-1.6.3.jar
axiom-api-1.2.14.jar
axiom-impl-1.2.14.jar
neethi-3.0.2.jar
stax-1.2.0.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
```

The weblogic.xml file has the following section.

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

The weblogic-application.xml file has this section.

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.bind.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.crypto.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.registry.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.rpc.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.stream.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.ws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

The MANIFEST file contains the following section.

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar;lib/axis2-adb-1.6.3.jar;lib/axis2-kernel-1.6.3.jar;lib/axis2-transport-base-1.6.3.jar;lib/axis2-transport-http-1.6.3.jar;lib/axis2-transport-local-1.6.3.jar;lib/axiom-api-1.2.14.jar;lib/axiom-impl-1.2.14.jar;lib/neethi-3.0.2.jar;lib/stax-1.2.0.jar;lib/XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar" />
```

Can anybody throw some light as to what might be going on?

Thanks

Patrick

Comment: Can you expand stax*.jar to the actual list of JARs included?

Comment: @AndreasVeither I have now expanded all JARs I include in the EAR lib directory. They are as follows. axis2-adb-1.6.3.jar axis2-kernel-1.6.3.jar axis2-transport-base-1.6.3.jar axis2-transport-http-1.6.3.jar axis2-transport-local-1.6.3.jar axiom-api-1.2.14.jar axiom-impl-1.2.14.jar neethi-3.0.2.jar stax-1.2.0.jar XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar

Comment: If the EAR contained stax-api-x.y.x.jar, then I would have an explanation, but not with stax-1.2.0.jar.

Comment: @AndreasVeither Could Weblogic be using its own stax rather than the one in the EAR? If so, how to "force" Weblogic to use what is in the EAR?

Comment: Yes it is using Weblogic's StAX implementation, but that doesn't explain the ClassCastException because (according to the list of JARs you have provided) your application doesn't contain any JAR with the javax.xml.stream package.

Comment: The stack trace actually shows Spring classes, but the corresponding JARs are not in the EAR. You should update your question to also include the list of JARs in the WAR.